# Editar dos campos de diferentes tablas en una consulta

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, phpmyadmin

Una pregunta, abría alguna forma de que cuando yo edite un campo especifico de una tabla, al tiempo me edite otro campo en otra (Base de datos = Mysql), puesto que tengo un campo tipo date y necesito que cuando modifique en especial ese campo me edite otro campo en una tabla diferente.

he intentado hacer una condición que cuando la actualización del campo especifico sea exitosa me edite el otro campo, solo que no se muy bien como hacerla.

Agradezco sus respuestas.

Comment: Poder se puede. Pero para obtener una respuesta clara deberías proporcionar un ejemplo de lo que tienes y quieres obtener. Una opción podría ser usando trigger: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/trigger-syntax.html

Answer (score 0):

Pienso que es mejor que lo hagas en el backend (PHP), puesto que estás evaluando si un campo específico fue modificado. Para hacer dos inserciones, puedes hacerlo mediante una transacción que empiece con BEGIN y termine con COMMIT. De todas formas, revisa [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5178713/7700985), tal vez tenga lo que buscas.